# Two Completed actions / Stated in one sentence – Simple Past

Tags: past-simple

Are my below examples are giving idea of two completed actions / stated in one sentences? 
I just want to know are my below sentence construction are correct? And can we use Past perfect for first completed action?

e.g.

a) I went to hotel (Being in hotel) where I saw that superstar.

b) I went to office (Being in office / was in office) at that time something happened at home.

c) When she called me at home at that time I Went to Market (Being in market / was in office)

d) She changed that paper (Completed action of Changing) before principal arrived at classroom.

e) Did she call me when I was not here?

f) 5 friends went to picnic when that accident happened with them.

Are my examples are giving two completed actions / stated in one sentences? 
I just want to know are my above sentence construction are correct? And can we use Past perfect in above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Simple corrections apply to the following sentences, look for the differences.

a) I went to the hotel (Being in a hotel) where I saw that superstar.

b) I went to the office (Being in an office / was in an office) at that time something happened at home.

d) She changed that paper (Completed action of Changing) before the principal arrived at the classroom.

e) Did she call me when I was not here?

f) 5 friends went to a picnic when that accident happened to them.

I left out c) as this requires more attention.

As written:
c) When she called me at home at that time I Went to Market (Being in market / was in office)

Writing this in certain ways can say different things regarding the order of events.

> When she called my home, I went to the Market.

The above says: she called me ***then*** I went to the market.

> At the time she called my home, I went to the market.

This says as she called my home, I ignored it and went to the market instead.

> When she called my home, I was at the market.

Here, and this is what I think you originally tried to say, we are saying as she called my home, I was at the market (at the same time).

If you apply these examples to your other sentences, you can see how a subtle change can drastically change what is said, or not at all in fact.